# OroCommerce Storefront json login issues

Tags: orocommerce

I need to make storefront login for the some js application and simplest way seemed to just add json-login to the frontend firewall using **app.yml** file in my bundle:

```
security:
  firewalls:
      frontend:
          json_login:
            check_path: json-login
```

this auth works perfectly, but unexpected issue happened with oro storefront itself - now the storefront index page faults with
Uncaught PHP Exception Error: "Call to a member function getId() on null" at vendor/oro/commerce/src/Oro/Bundle/CatalogBundle/Layout/DataProvider/FeaturedCategoriesProvider.php line 106:

```
            $this->tokenAccessor->getOrganization()->getId()
```

Whats wrong with auth, why this issue happening while auth itself works?

If any will try to reproduce issue (just add lines to app.yml) note that you should always make prorep login/logout before changing app.yml or issue may happen with no yml changes or not happen with changes, probably it depends on token data in session

Upd: I checked session data and really with default config session contains
`"Oro\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordOrganizationToken"`

and after json-login added it will contain
`"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken"`
but why this happening? Im not changing any token config and even dont need than, only need json login for the storefront.

Answer (score 1):

The security token in Oro must implement the `Oro\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Authentication\Token\OrganizationAwareTokenInterface` interface.

You can use one of many [existing implementations](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/search?q=implements%20OrganizationAwareTokenInterface) if it fits your needs or create a new one.

There are several built-in, ready to use, authentication methods that you can use in the JS application to access Oro API: [oAuth2 and WSSE](https://doc.oroinc.com/api/authentication/).

Comment: Okay, but Im not creating any new authentification just added json-login to existing preconfigured to use proper token. And issue happens when Im using standard login to oro storefront, not json login

Comment: The idea is that you cannot use existing authentication methods like json_login without extending them because Symfony doesn't know about the token requirements in OroCommerce.

Comment: I extended the answer a few with alternatives, you can use oob for authentication from the JS application.